# ColdFusion: HTML <Button> tag sets FORM scope value differently in IE 11 vs other browsers

Tags: html, forms, post, coldfusion, internet-explorer-11

In the following code sample...

---

```
<CFOUTPUT>

    <cfdump var=#FORM#> 

    <FORM NAME="LAYOUTFORM" ACTION="" id="TEST_FORM" METHOD=POST>

        <BR> <BR> <BR> 

        <div class="div">
            <button  type="submit" form="TEST_FORM" name="test" type="submit" value="BUTTON-VALUE" >  THIS IS NOT THE VALUE YOU WERE HOPING FOR</button>
        </div>
    </FORM>

</CFOUTPUT>
```

---

After clicking the button and submitting the post request ...   
On **Google Chrome**, **Mozilla Firefox**, and **Microsoft Edge** I received the expected result after dumping the FORM scope

```
[FieldNames | Test] 
[Test       | Button-Value]
```

---

After Submitting click on **Internet Explorer 11** I received different results

```
[FieldNames | Test                                      ] 
[Test       | THIS IS NOT THE VALUE YOU WERE HOPING FOR ]
```

It appears that instead of using the `value`, IE 11 submits whats between `<BUTTON>` tags

I found a note on https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_button_value.asp

> Note: If you use the  element in an HTML form, Internet
>   Explorer, prior version 8, will submit the text between the 
>   and  tags, while the other browsers will submit the content
>   of the value attribute.

This appears to be the same behavior, but I'm using IE 11.... 
 I also tried the try-me example and the the correct values are submitted with the button when submitting to the `action_page.php`

---

1. Anyone has any insight into why IE-11 is submitting as if it was IE-8 if a ColdFusion page is the target? (I haven't touched IE compatibility settings)
2. Are there solutions other then making the `value` same as whats between the `<Button>` tags?

Comment: `form="TEST_FORM"` and `type="submit"` existing twice looks strange. You probably have to set the value to get the same value all the time. Or just use <input type="submit" value="Whatever" >

Comment: Like James said, remove `form="TEST_FORM"` from the button, and one of the extra `type="submit"`. I think the `form` attribute of a `button` us usually applicable if the button is outside of the `form` tags. I think it's not supported in IE. And having an attribute twice _SHOULDN'T_ break the HTML, but it's IE, so all bets are off.

Comment: whoops! good catch .. didn't notice the extra submit, but removing both the form and submit attribute didn't change whats passed with the Post request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It might be the `X-UA-Compatible` header. Or IE is acting funky based on what it sees in the page.
2. Instead of using a `button` to pass a form variable, use `<input type="hidden" name="abc" value="xyz">`. Buttons are made to perform actions. Inputs are made to hold values.

Comment: Adding <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11"> in between the <head> tags did the trick

Comment: I'm glad that's working for you. Still, consider #2 to future-proof your form.

Comment: Wanted to add ....  because the Application.cfc is called before the form page if any markup is generated in the Application.cfc before the <X-UA-Compatible> tag ... it will ignore it, so I needed to set the tag first thing in the onRequest() method

Comment: I do something similar in `onRequest()`: `<cfheader name="content-type" value="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<cfheader name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge" />
<cfheader name="window-target" value="_top" />
<cfheader name="imagetoolbar" value="no" />`